# Instantons as classical solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiclassical, instantons

Instantons are classical solutions of the *Euclidean* (i.e. imaginary time) classical equations of motion.

The standard example from single particle 1D QM is taking a potential of the form $V(x)=(x^2-a^2)^2$ and looking for solutions $\gamma$ for $$ \ddot{\gamma} = +V'(\gamma) = 4 (\gamma^2-a^2)\gamma \tag{CoM}$$ 
(note the plus sign on the potential--this is Euclidean time).

An approximate solution for this is for example given by $\gamma(t) = a \tanh(\pm\sqrt{2}a(t-t_0))$ for any $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ (there's a family of solutions indexed by $t_0$).

Say we are looking for solutions which obey the boundary conditions $\gamma(\pm T) = \pm a$ over a time period $[-T,T]$ for some $T$. Then the solution with the $+$ variant, the so-called single instanton solution, will obey the boundary conditions *only in the limit $T\to\infty$*. Be that as it may, we press on and realize that we can also concatenate solutions with alternating $\pm$ variatns in order to still obey the boundary conditions, so we can get instanton-anti-instanton-instanton string which is called the 3-instanton solution. This is, again, only an approximate solution of CoM.

One verifies that if the action of one instanton is $S_0$ then the action of a concatenation of $n$ instantons is $n S_0$.

**My question**: One could just as well characterize solutions of CoM by saying they minimize the action. When stated like that, the multi-instanton solutions are *not* minimizers of the action since they are actually integer multiples of it. So how can they be called approximate classical solutions, as opposed to the single instanton solutions, which are approximate only in the sense that they obey the BC only in the $T\to\infty$ limit?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here. The first is about boundary conditions in the single instanton sector. This is easily remedied, there is an exact solution of the equations of motion that satisfies the boundary condition for finite $T$, see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321382904771?via%3Dihub).

The second issue is more complicated. The question is whether the two-instanton (instanton-anti-instanton), or three instanton (two-instanton-anti-instanton) etc, configurations are saddle points of the path integral. Indeed, they cannot be ordinary saddle points, because the instanton-anti-instanton configuration lives in the same topological sector as the perturbative vacuum, so the configuration is smoothly connected to the vacuum solution. These configurations exist as saddle points of the complexified path integral. The corresponding saddle point manifolds are known as Lefshetz thimbles, see, for example, [here](http://inspirehep.net/record/1665487?ln=en).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So just to double-check: my main misconception was that I conflated solutions of CoM as minimizers of the action, whereas they are extremum points of the action, which could just as well be saddle points, and the multi-instanton solutions are precisely saddle points? Furthermore, you seem to indicate that they are not "ordinary saddle points", but can you elaborate why true saddle points (how are they defined? as zeros of S'?) cannot be in the same topological sector of the vacuum?

Comment: @PPR Sorry for increasing confusion. The term "saddle" is just a generic term, because we are trying to find the path integral analog of the saddle point approximation to ordinary integrals. For a purely real integral of the form $e^{-S}$ we would seem to need true minima of the action (we can have exactly flat directions, leading to collective coordinate integrals). The instanton is indeed a true minimum in QM (and has exactly flat directions in YM theory).

Comment: However, the instanton-anti-instanton configuration is certainly not a minimum (indeed, not even an ordinary saddle point), because at finite sepration it does not solve the equations of motion. It has to be interpreted in terms of Picard-Lefshetz theory, as explained in the linked paper.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I am indeed interested in the simplest, QM 1D double well example which in Euclidean time is a real path integral. However, let me insist: if we _do take the limit $T\to\infty$, then the instanton-anti-instanton-instanton string is still not a minimum, right? Because its action equals $3 S_0$. So why are we looking at these strings when performing the dilute instanton gas approximation?

Comment: @PPR The IAI has an action $\sim 3S_0$, but it is continuously connected to the I configuration, so the minimum action in this sector is $S_0$. If the IAI are well separated, then the dependence of the action on IA separation is exponentially small, so people have the intuition that it should be possible to treat this as a flat direction, which gives the standard instanton gas formula. This intuition is ultimately correct, but it takes some work to justify it more rigorously, which is what the linked paper attempts to do.

Comment: what do you mean by flat direction? Sorry I am approaching this from a very naive perspective: generalizing the Laplace approximation (which integrates over R^n) to integration over path space, we still need to consider _only_ minima of the functional within the exponent. Why is any path that is not a minimum relevant for this approximation?

Comment: @PPR Sorry, I actually misspoke earlier. Even the instaton in QM has a flat direction (the action is independent of the instanton location). This is fine, we can separate out the integration over the instanton position, and treat the remaining path integral via the saddle point method.

Comment: sorry to be stirring cold coffee, but I've tried reading on Lefschetz thimbles and from what I could understand they are introduced to solve a sign problem in the path integral, i.e., the fact the action in Euclidean time is no longer purely positive. However, for the double well problem, if I undersatnd correctly, there is no sign problem. So why is it necessary to complexify the paths?

Comment: is the need to consider longer instanton-anti-instanton strings related somehow to what is referred to in statistical mechanics as minimizing the free energy rather than minimizing the energy? I.e., even though a 3 instanton string may have higher energy, it occupies more volume in path space compared to the single instanton configuration? etc?

Comment: @PPR Phyiscists learned about Lefschetz thimbles from Witten's paper on Chern-Simons theory (https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6032), which has nothing to do with the sign problem. Applications to instantons and the semi-classical expansion are also not related to the sign problem. The idea to apply thimbles to the sign problem came later.

Comment: @PPR Why complexify is a good question, but the need to compelexify is not unique to the path integral. This already happens in standard asymptotic expansions of ordinary integrals (Witten discusses the Airy function as an example).

Comment: @PPR The free energy vs energy comment is correct, but in some ways the situation is even simpler. The total tunneling rate involves an integral over the instanton 'position' (in time), and is infinite. So really, we consider the rate per unit time, and the relevant path integral is over a configuration with a finite density of instantons. So we always have to consider a gas of instantons and anti-instantons (as explained, for example, in Coleman's lectures).